# Calling overloaded constructors fails in if statement

Tags: c++, class, constructor

So I have an if statement that decides whether one or another constructor is called. This is the code that gives me the error:

```
detect::Wrapper detector;

if (detectorFileNameSpecified){
  detector = detect::Wrapper(detectorFileName,
             saveImages,
             learnOrDetect,
             verbosity);
}
else {
  detector = detect::Wrapper(saveImages,
             learnOrDetect,
             verbosity);
}

detector.setFind(findAlgNo);
detector.setLD(LDAlgNo);

detector.run();
```

g++ gives me these kinds of errors:

```
main.cpp:126:15: error: use of deleted function ‘detect::Wrapper& detect::Wrapper::operator=(detect::Wrapper&&)’
      verbosity);
               ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
wrapper.hpp:14:9: note: ‘detect::Wrapper& detect::Wrapper::operator=(detect::Wrapper&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   class Wrapper{
         ^~~~~~~
```

However if I do it the naive way of creating redundant code it works perfectly.

```
if (detectorFileNameSpecified){
      detect::Wrapper detector(detectorFileName,
                   saveImages,
                   learnOrDetect,
                   verbosity);

      detector.setFind(findAlgNo);
      detector.setLD(LDAlgNo);

      detector.run();
    }
    else {
      detect::Wrapper detector(saveImages,
                   learnOrDetect,
                   verbosity);

      detector.setFind(findAlgNo);
      detector.setLD(LDAlgNo);

      detector.run();
    }
```

All I want to do is reduce the redundancy in my code and not have to write the .setFind() etc. part every time I need a different constructor. I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: The error doesn't complain about the constructor, but about the assignment operator. Apparently, `detect::Wrapper` is not copy-assignable. That's why `detector = whatever;` doesn't work, regardless of what `whatever` is.

Comment: You could use `?:` instead of `if`/`else`.

Comment: Is your class move-constructible ? (it is already not move assignable).

Comment: The error message is complaining about line 126 in your source code. The code you posted does not have 126 lines. Post the smallest example you can come up with that **reproduces the problem**. Don't leave it to readers to try to figure out what's missing and cobble toghether something that might or might not be the same as what you're looking at.

Comment: You could have simply declared a `detect::Wrapper*` and point to the `detect::Wrapper` that you've created, then use the pointer from there on.

Comment: You could of course factor the common three calls out to a separate function and then only call `FindLoadAndRun(detector);` for each alternative. Cuts redundancy by 2/3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating function:

```
void doJob(detect::Wrapper&& detector)
{
    detector.setFind(findAlgNo);
    detector.setLD(LDAlgNo);

    detector.run();
}
```

You may then factorize your code to:

```
if (detectorFileNameSpecified){
    doJob(detect::Wrapper(detectorFileName, saveImages, learnOrDetect, verbosity));
} else {
    doJob(detect::Wrapper(saveImages, learnOrDetect, verbosity));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to avoid code duplication is using a pointer and circumvent the deleted assignment operator:

```
std::unique_ptr<detect::Wrapper> detector; // <<<<<<<<<<<

if (detectorFileNameSpecified){
  detector = std::make_unique<detect::Wrapper>(detectorFileName,
                                               saveImages,
                                               learnOrDetect,
                                               verbosity);
}
else {
  detector = std::make_unique<detect::Wrapper>(saveImages,
                                               learnOrDetect,
                                               verbosity);
}

// Note the -> to dereference    
detector->setFind(findAlgNo);
detector->setLD(LDAlgNo);

detector->run();
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that this comes with a runtime cost.